# PHP making a Forum with a database, can't get the links working

Tags: php, codeigniter

So i am making a simple forum to learn some PHP with CodeIgniter, by simple i mean 1 page with posts and you can click on them to comment and view more info(Think of reddit). All the data is stored in a mySQL database. Anyways i got all the links to display on my page, but what i cant figure out is how to open a new page to show the description and comments of the post. I remember doing something similar with  a long time ago, can't remember how i did that sadly.

```
<?php
   foreach($records as $rec){
$test = $rec->PostName."<br/>";  
Echo "<a href=#$test>$test</a>";
   }        
   ?>

    <?php
      echo '<div data-role="page" id="$test"></div>';
   echo "THIS ISSSSS $test";   
   ?>
```

So this is the part where i need help. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated

Comment: Echo '<a href="#$test">$test</a>';

Comment: take a deep breath - now look at this line: $test = $rec->PostName."<br/>"; a link is not going to work with a break <br> tag.

Comment: that <br> just separates the results, what i need to do is open a new page with depending on the HREF clicked.

Comment: PHP variables won't be evaluated in a string delimited with single-quote `'` characters, but will be in a string delimited with double-quote `"` characters.  Your second-to-last echo statement will literally output **<div data-role="page" id="$test"></div>**

Comment: No it doesnt, clicking on the href outputs HomeController#Barack which means its working. And the strings are surrounded by " ". So i dont understand your comment, because it doesnt output that

Comment: Have look here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#anchor

Comment: and http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#creating-loops

Answer (score 0):

Well for starters you'll need to refactor your attempt at generating the links as that has issues as everyone has pointed out.
So I took the liberty to come up with some test code to demonstrate a few things.

So this is Part 1.

```
<?php
// Simulated Database results, an array of objects
//
// These may already be Slugs with First letter upper case, hyphenated between words
// But I will do that when generating the links.
$records = [
    (object)['PostName'=>'Why I recommend reading more PHP Tutorials'],
    (object)['PostName'=>'Why I should take heed of what others suggest and actually try them out before dismissing them'],
    (object)['PostName'=>'What is the difference between using single and double quotes in strings'],
    (object)['PostName'=>'Why everyone should know how to use their browsers View Source tool to inspect the generated HTML'],
];

foreach ( $records as $rec ) {
    $test = $rec->PostName;
    // This would make a good helper but Codeigniter might have something already.
    // So you should go and read the manual.
    echo "<a href=\"#".ucfirst(str_replace(' ','-',$test))."\">$test</a>";
    // The above uses " to wrap the string with escaped \" within the string
    // cause you cant have both.
    echo '<br>';
}
// This is only here for testing... I think.
echo '<div data-role="page" id="'.$test.'"></div>';
// The above uses single quotes to wrap the string.
echo "THIS ISSSSS $test";
```

**Part of Part 2...**

```
<?php
// Simulated Database results, an array of objects
//
//
// These may already be Slugs with First letter upper case, hyphenated between words
// But I will do that when generating the links.
$records = [
    (object)[
        'id'=>1,
        'PostName'=>'Why I recommend reading more PHP Tutorials'],
    (object)[
        'id'=>2,
        'PostName'=>'What is the difference between using single and double quotes in strings'],
];

foreach ( $records as $rec ) {
    $name = $rec->PostName;
    $id = $rec->id;
    // The slug of the page isn't really being used here as
    // we are providing the pages id for lookup via an AJAX Call.
    echo "<a id=".$id." href=\"#".ucfirst(str_replace(' ','-',$name))."\">$name</a>";
    echo '<br>';
}
// This is where the AJAX call fired by a click on an anchor, that sends the id
// which results in the fetching of the required details to plonk in our page-area div.
echo '<div class="page-area"></div>';
```

There are a number of ways to do this, but going totally basic, if we create a JS event for a click on an anchor.. Which fires an AJAX Call which posts the page id to our method that returns back the HTML of the results we want to display...

Comment: Well sadly wont let me upvote =/...curious to see how you will manage the links, im really starting to hate php at this point

Comment: Ahh it's fun :) You just need to sit back and take your time and think about it :) It doesn't happen overnight... I'm always picking up new things on here so you have a good resource... :) So the next bit...

Comment: My initial plan was to use the href as ID's and then load the rest of the post from the DB...but i cant even get a new page to open when i click on the link. Pretty sure all i used last time was <div ids...

Comment: Yep, you can use your pages ids as the id for each link... ie <a href="#" id="<?= the_page_id;?>" and perform and fire an AJAX call on clicking of a link and grabbing it's id, which will need a handler method to deal with it. Ring any bells? So you don't really need the page name in the href at all except for prettyness if that's your thing...

Comment: If memory serves i did   <a href="#TESTID">The link to click</a>                and then to follow up  <div data-role="page"  id="TESTID">...and that would open a new page for me. But in this scenario it just wont work. Unless im derping very hard :D

Comment: Just appended another piece of the puzzle to my answer.

Comment: Seem to be moving foward here...i get the ID's of each post i click, so i can use that to load the rest from the DB. Now to create a sub-page of sort to show my querie results

Comment: Sounds like a cunning plan :)

Comment: Think i might have screwed myself over here. I can get the new page setup AND grab the id from the link, however because the ID is in jquery it doesnt transfer over since php is server sided. Gonna go work now, gonna resume this after :D